# Changing transport's recv and send methods

Tags: python, python-asyncio, sctp

I am trying to implement a SCTP and asyncio based client using `pysctp` sockets. Ideally, I would like to do something like:

```
async def sctp_client():
    sock = sctp.sctpsocket_udp(socket.AF_INET)
    reader, writer = await asyncio.open_connection(sock=sock)
    writer.write(b'some data', ppid=5)
    await writer.drain()
    data = await reader.read(100)
    print(f'Received: {data.decode()}')
    writer.close()
    await writer.wait_closed()
```

In practice, there are two question:

- **Is there a way to pass a "transport factory" to `open_connection` or to `loop.create_connection`?**
  I want the transport object contained by the streams to use `sctp_recv` instead of `recv` and `sctp_send` instead of `send`. Clearly the easiest way is to derive from the original transport class, but I couldn't find a good pythonic way to do it.
- **Is there a way to get a custom `StreamWriter` from `open_connection`?** Obviously I could create my own one from the original, add a method to the original or just access the internal transport but these options are awfully ugly. The second best way I can think about is just to implement my own `open_connection` using the `loop.create_connection`.

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

Looking at the [source code](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/3.9/Lib/asyncio/streams.py#L25-L55), there is no way to provide a factory to `asyncio.open_connection`. That said, the code there isn't terribly complex. Note the last line of the docstring:

> (If you want to customize the StreamReader and/or
> StreamReaderProtocol classes, just copy the code -- there's
> really nothing special here except some convenience.)

That's exactly what I'd recommend doing.

Comment: Thanks! this is what I thought. Do you also have any insights about replacing `recv` and `send`?

Comment: Sure. Note that the first argument of [`loop.create_connection`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/asyncio-eventloop.html#asyncio.loop.create_connection) is called `protocol_factory`. You'll need to find (or write) an implementation of the [`Protocol` interface](https://docs.python.org/3/library/asyncio-protocol.html#protocols) that uses the transport you need.

Comment: The problem is that the transport is created independently from the protocol and the `recv` and `send` are used in the transport and not the protocol - so protocol factory will not help here.